# angularjs ajax json is not get the value with html

Tags: angularjs

I know the problem that json is not get the value with html tags and it cause a issue of httpbaddata:

here is the error which stops to get data from db:

```
    angular.js:14525 Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/baddata?p0=%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%22records%22%3A%5B%7B%220%22%3A%20%227318%22%2C%22term_taxonomy_id%22%3A%20%227318%22%2C%221%22%3A%20%227318%22%2C%22term_id%22%3A%20%227318%22%2C%222%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%22taxonomy%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%223%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%20works%20equally%20well%20on%20men%20and%20women%3B%20it%20is%20safe%20for%20use%20anywhere%20on%20the%20body%20and%20it%20only%20requires%20one%20simple%20application.%20It%20will%20be%20absorbed%20quickly%20and%20removed%20instantaneously.%20Our%20product%20has%20proven%20to%20eliminate%20regular%20shaving%2C%20waxing%20and%20the%20use%20of%20tweezers%2C%20not%20to%20mention%20the%20hassle%20and%20the%20expense%20of%20Electrolysis%20and%20Laser%20treatments.%20Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%20is%20the%20most%20effective%20alternative%20to%20expensive%20laser%20treatments%20and%20electrolysis.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%20works%20equally%20well%20on%20men%20and%20women%3B%20it%20is%20safe%20for%20use%20anywhere%20on%20the%20body%20and%20it%20only%20requires%20one%20simple%20application.%20It%20will%20be%20absorbed%20quickly%20and%20removed%20instantaneously.%20Our%20product%20has%20proven%20to%20eliminate%20regular%20shaving%2C%20waxing%20and%20the%20use%20of%20tweezers%2C%20not%20to%20mention%20the%20hassle%20and%20the%20expense%20of%20Electrolysis%20and%20Laser%20treatments.%20Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%20is%20the%20most%20effective%20alternative%20to%20expensive%20laser%20treatments%20and%20electrolysis.%22%2C%224%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22parent%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%225%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%22count%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%226%22%3A%20%227318%22%2C%227%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%22%2C%22name%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Hair%20Removal%20Cream%22%2C%228%22%3A%20%22revitol-hair-removal-cream-coupons%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%20%22revitol-hair-removal-cream-coupons%22%2C%229%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22term_group%22%3A%20%220%22%7D%2C%7B%220%22%3A%20%227282%22%2C%22term_taxonomy_id%22%3A%20%227282%22%2C%221%22%3A%20%227282%22%2C%22term_id%22%3A%20%227282%22%2C%222%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%22taxonomy%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%223%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Scar%20Cream%20removes%20the%20appearance%20of%20Acne%20Scars%2C%20Burns%2C%20cuts%2C%20gashes%20and%20scars%20caused%20by%20surgery.%20We%EF%BF%BDve%20worked%20hard%20to%20develop%20a%20blend%20of%20all-natural%20ingredients%20that%20fortify%20your%20skin%20with%20proteins%20and%20vitamins.%20This%20formula%20helps%20combat%20the%20causes%20of%20scarring%20and%20heal%20skin%20from%20scars%20caused%20by%20acne%2C%20burns%2C%20and%20other%20factors%20in%20a%20way%20that%EF%BF%BDs%20both%20safe%20and%20effective.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Scar%20Cream%20removes%20the%20appearance%20of%20Acne%20Scars%2C%20Burns%2C%20cuts%2C%20gashes%20and%20scars%20caused%20by%20surgery.%20We%EF%BF%BDve%20worked%20hard%20to%20develop%20a%20blend%20of%20all-natural%20ingredients%20that%20fortify%20your%20skin%20with%20proteins%20and%20vitamins.%20This%20formula%20helps%20combat%20the%20causes%20of%20scarring%20and%20heal%20skin%20from%20scars%20caused%20by%20acne%2C%20burns%2C%20and%20other%20factors%20in%20a%20way%20that%EF%BF%BDs%20both%20safe%20and%20effective.%22%2C%224%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22parent%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%225%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%22count%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%226%22%3A%20%227282%22%2C%227%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Scar%20Cream%22%2C%22name%22%3A%20%22Revitol%20Scar%20Cream%22%2C%228%22%3A%20%22revitol-scar-cream-coupons%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%20%22revitol-scar-cream-coupons%22%2C%229%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22term_group%22%3A%20%220%22%7D%2C%7B%220%22%3A%20%227281%22%2C%22term_taxonomy_id%22%3A%20%227281%22%2C%221%22%3A%20%227281%22%2C%22term_id%22%3A%20%227281%22%2C%222%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%22taxonomy%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%223%22%3A%20%22Curcumin%20plays%20a%20vital%20role%20in%20protecting%20your%20body%20against%20painful%20and%20dangerous%20inflammation.%20By%20utilizing%20a%20unique%20curcumin%20extract%20and%20binding%20this%20ingredient%20to%20a%20high%20quality%20absorption%20agent%2C%20Curcumin%202000%20is%20able%20to%20introduce%20the%20bioavailabilty%20equivalent%20of%2042%2C000mg%20of%20any%20other%20curcumin%20supplement%20on%20the%20market.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%20%22Curcumin%20plays%20a%20vital%20role%20in%20protecting%20your%20body%20against%20painful%20and%20dangerous%20inflammation.%20By%20utilizing%20a%20unique%20curcumin%20extract%20and%20binding%20this%20ingredient%20to%20a%20high%20quality%20absorption%20agent%2C%20Curcumin%202000%20is%20able%20to%20introduce%20the%20bioavailabilty%20equivalent%20of%2042%2C000mg%20of%20any%20other%20curcumin%20supplement%20on%20the%20market.%22%2C%224%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22parent%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%225%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%22count%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%226%22%3A%20%227281%22%2C%227%22%3A%20%22Curcumin%202000%22%2C%22name%22%3A%20%22Curcumin%202000%22%2C%228%22%3A%20%22curcumin-2000-coupons%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%20%22curcumin-2000-coupons%22%2C%229%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22term_group%22%3A%20%220%22%7D%2C%7B%220%22%3A%20%227173%22%2C%22term_taxonomy_id%22%3A%20%227173%22%2C%221%22%3A%20%227173%22%2C%22term_id%22%3A%20%227173%22%2C%222%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%22taxonomy%22%3A%20%22stores%22%2C%223%22%3A%20%22Stop%20Grow%20hair%20inhibitor%20by%20SkinCeption%20has%20a%20scientifically%20formulated%20hair%20removal%20gel%20that%20greatly%20reduce%20the%20amount%20of%20hair%20growth%20after%20just%20the%20first%20use.%20This%20product%20is%20more%20gentle%20than%20a%20hot%20wax%20or%20depilatory%20cream%20and%20can%20be%20used%20on%20even%20the%20most%20sensitive%20of%20skin.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23000080%5C%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ESpecifically%2C%20it%5C's%20designed%20to%3A%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E1-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20interrupt%20the%20anagen%20phase%20of%20body%20hair%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E2-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20thin%20out%20existing%20growth%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E3-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20reduce%20length%20of%20body%20hair%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E4-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20decrease%20the%20need%20to%20wax%20or%20shave%22%2C%22description%22%3A%20%22Stop%20Grow%20hair%20inhibitor%20by%20SkinCeption%20has%20a%20scientifically%20formulated%20hair%20removal%20gel%20that%20greatly%20reduce%20the%20amount%20of%20hair%20growth%20after%20just%20the%20first%20use.%20This%20product%20is%20more%20gentle%20than%20a%20hot%20wax%20or%20depilatory%20cream%20and%20can%20be%20used%20on%20even%20the%20most%20sensitive%20of%20skin.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23000080%5C%22%3E%3Cstrong%3ESpecifically%2C%20it%5C's%20designed%20to%3A%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E1-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20interrupt%20the%20anagen%20phase%20of%20body%20hair%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E2-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20thin%20out%20existing%20growth%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E3-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20reduce%20length%20of%20body%20hair%0D%0A%3Cstrong%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%5C%22color%3A%20%23800000%5C%22%3E4-%3C%5C%2Fspan%3E%3C%5C%2Fstrong%3E%20decrease%20the%20need%20to%20wax%20or%20shave%22%2C%224%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22parent%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%225%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%22count%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%226%22%3A%20%227173%22%2C%227%22%3A%20%22Stop%20Grow%22%2C%22name%22%3A%20%22Stop%20Grow%22%2C%228%22%3A%20%22stop-grow-coupons%22%2C%22slug%22%3A%20%22stop-grow-coupons%22%2C%229%22%3A%20%220%22%2C%22term_group%22%3A%20%220%22%7D%5D%7D&p1=%7B%7D
    at angular.js:38
    at nc (angular.js:11177)
    at angular.js:11270
    at q (angular.js:403)
    at xd (angular.js:11269)
    at f (angular.js:12090)
    at angular.js:16832
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17971)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18269)
    at l (angular.js:12387) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14525
```

This is the code of my terms.php file which contains all the information with key and value

```
include_once 'db.php';
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $sel_query = "SELECT `wp_term_taxonomy`.*,`wp_terms`.* FROM  `wp_term_taxonomy`,`wp_terms` WHERE `wp_terms`.`term_id` = `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id` AND `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'stores'  GROUP BY `wp_terms`.`term_id`  ORDER BY `wp_terms`.`term_id` DESC LIMIT 4";
    $sel_res = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sel_res) > 0){
        $outp = "";
        $i = 0;
        while($sel_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel_res)){
            $outp .= '{';
            foreach ($sel_row  as $key => $value) {
                $value = str_ireplace(array('"','/','&nbsp;',"'"), array('\"','\/','',"\'"), $value);
                $outp .= '"'. $key.'": "' . $value . '",';
            }
            $outp .=  '},';
        }
        $outp = str_ireplace(',}', '}', '{"records":['.$outp.']}');
        $outp = str_ireplace(',]', ']', $outp);
        echo $outp;
    }
```

Now the angular js script:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('myController', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.display_data = function(){
        $http.get("terms.php").then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = [response.data.records];

        });
    }
});
```

Here is my frontend code:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
            <div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="display_data()">
                <table>

                    <tr ng-repeat="x in myData[0]">
                        <td ng-bind="x.name"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON output method may have an error. JSON has a syntax, if there is an extra comma or incorrect bracket placing, JSON reading will fail.

PHP has JSON reading and writing functions. Use it like below:

```
$json_array = [];
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
    $json_array[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

You can remove the `if` as well. The `while` will only run till it has all the rows. If there are no rows, while will not run at all and your JSON response will be an empty JSON Array.

Also `fetch_assoc` will use the keys from your sql queries.

Try this out and comment if it works for you.

Regards

Comment: sir i appreciate your response but i have more than 1 row from my db if i gave a index to my array then it works corectly but what would i do if i want more than 1 data........................................................... $json_array = [];
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_res)){
    $json_array[] = $data;
}

for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($sel_res); $i++ ){
 echo str_ireplace('}','},',json_encode($json_array[$i]));
}